# What exactly is Xpath and what browsers support it

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to know what Xpath is (in brief), which browsers support it and how to use it. I tried using document.evaluate() but it returns a DOM error. Are there specific doc types which can use it. A little get me started info would be nice.

Comment: -1: Have you Googled "**xpath**"?

Comment: I did.but couldn't quite find a gist. I tried some xpath methods. Didn't work. Wouldn't ask the question otherwise. I am looking for a gistsort of

Comment: The best way to learn is to try things out for yourself. Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: You could also hover over the xpath tag in your question for a brief description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath is a query syntax for XML-like documents. If you are familiar with SQL, it performs a similar function.

As for browser support, I don't know of a way to test. Google Chrome's web inspector lets you test Xpath expressions using $x().